# Minecraft make an individual 50/50 check

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have encountered a problem while trying to make a simple function that restocks chests in a map.

My Current code:

```
execute at @e[tag=t1_1] run loot replace block ~ ~ ~ container.0 27 loot minecraft:empty
execute at @e[tag=t1_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ air
execute at @e[tag=t1_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{LootTable:"house:chests/t1"}

execute at @e[tag=t2_1] run loot replace block ~ ~ ~ container.0 27 loot minecraft:empty
execute at @e[tag=t2_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ air
execute at @e[tag=t2_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{LootTable:"house:chests/t2"}

execute at @e[tag=t3_1] run loot replace block ~ ~ ~ container.0 27 loot minecraft:empty
execute at @e[tag=t3_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ air
execute at @e[tag=t3_1] run setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{LootTable:"house:chests/t3"}
```

I'm trying to make not place all chests and remove some of them. I couldnt figure out if this was possible with loot tables, and the normal way doesnt really work because of how its currently coded.
Is there any way someone can help?

---

Update:
I modified the loot table to sometimes spawn a stone in it, and if it does the chest gets removed.
Code:

```
execute as @e[tag=t3_1] run execute at @s if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone"}]} run setblock ~ ~ ~ air
```

One major problem is that it just straight will not work in a function. It works in a command block and in in-game chat, and if the function is called manually by a player. But it wont work if its in the function mentioned above.
I'm confused.

Comment: What entitys are getting the tags your using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a data pack (otherwise how would you have those loot tables), so I would recommend using a `random_chance` predicate to make a 50-50 decision.

Such predicate would look like this:

```
{
  "condition": "minecraft:random_chance",
  "chance": 0.5
}
```

It would go at this file path:

```
/data/<namespace>/predicates/<predicate_name>.json
```

And you could call upon it like this, this would make the command run only 50% of the time:

```
execute if predicate <namespace>:<predicate_name> run ...
```